# What does the parameter 'statement-id' of 'add-permission' mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-lambda

I'm working through the tutorial ["Walkthrough 2: Handling Amazon S3 Events (Node.js)"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-configure-s3.html). I have a question about the CLI parameters:

```
 aws lambda add-permission \
--function-name CreateThumbnail \
--region us-west-2 \
--statement-id some-unique-id \
--action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
--principal s3.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket \
--source-account bucket-owner-account-id \
--profile adminuser
```

What is the parameter `--statement-id some-unique-id`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an arbitrary/opaque identifier that you essentially make up.  In some situations, it's optional.  In IAM policies, this is shown as the `Sid`.  An example might be simply `1` or `MyStringIMadeUp12345`.  It's typically used to describe or track the policy and has no meaning to AWS.  Some services impose uniqueness constraints, meaning that each statement has to have a unique Sid.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Sid